# Prevent certain fields from showing up when changing values

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

After a user goes through the form and hits the confirmation step, if they say no, a card is shown asking what they would like to change.  I have certain calculated fields that I don't want to show up there.  How can I prevent them from showing up there?

For example, if the user enters their birthday, I calculate their age.  If during the confirmation step they say "No", I don't want Age to show up in the list of fields they are able to change, only birthday.  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: one thing that comes to mind is maybe getting this data from the user outside of formflow and storing them in one of the `IDataBags` in the `Context` object and have the user confirm those outside of your main form.  You could also most likely accomplish the same thing with local variables depending on your implementation.  Could you update your question with your code so we can better assist you please?